# Remove the array that is already in another array

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

How can i remove the elements of array that is from another array

Here is my Array Alpha `["1","2","4"]`

And the Array Beta ["1"]

How can i remove the elements of Array Alpha that already contains in Array Beta

i.e., After removal it will remove the 1 as it is contained in Array Beta and returns only `["2","4"]`

Comment: You can use `unset(Array_Alpha['1']);`.

Comment: use array_diff($alpha,$beta);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `array_diff`:

```
array_diff($alpha, $beta);
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/fZRGD

Comment: It returns me `{"0":"1"}` But How can i get like this ["1"] ?

Comment: `{"0":"1"}` looks like json, are you json_encoding your array? If you look at my example, it returns `["2","4"]` exactly like you requested.

Comment: No i am not json_encoding the result. But it comes like that.. How can i overcome it ? Should i do json_decode or anything to get like that ?

Comment: I think you need to go read up on PHP arrays. There's nothing to overcome. Have you looked at the example link I posted? It does what you wanted, provides the `alpha` array with the `beta` array values removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = [1,2,4];
$b = [1];
$a = array_diff($a,$b);
print_r($a);
```

Yields:

```
Array ( [1] => 2 [2] => 4 )
```

And if you don't want to preserve original keys, you take only array of values:

```
$a = array_values(array_diff($a,$b));
print_r($a);
```

Then it gives:

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 )
```

Comment: It returns me {"0":"1"} But How can i get like this ["1"] ?

Comment: you wanted to delete "1", not "2" and "4"? Anyway if you ask about difference, array ["1"] is the same as array(0=>"1") - every value has its key.